# Convert unicode list into python list

Tags: python

```
s = u"['1', '2', '2', '1', '2']"
print type(s) # <type 'unicode'>
```

How can I convert this into list like here:

```
s = [1,2,2,1,2]
```

Comment: And how did you end up with such a string in the first place? Perhaps we can suggest better ways to communicate or store a list?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `ast.literal_eval` function.

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = u"['1', '2', '2', '1', '2']"
>>> list(map(int, ast.literal_eval(s)))
[1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

OR

```
>>> [int(i) for i in ast.literal_eval(s)]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Is this a valid way to? [int(item) for item in s]